# How to set X-Frame-Options => ALLOWALL for accounts.google.com authentication link (OAuth)?

Tags: javascript, iframe, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I have a website with Google OAuth authentication link. The website is displayed through iframe on another website. When I click on Google OAuth link, it redirects me to

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope%.....

and returns the response with the header    `x-frame-options:DENY`

and an error

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&contin…iFDca2N1r2ts6Lm8zTYJ7Pcj9938uKAEyFOgJCaYaq1wNz_yGrWE59Hv73BWk&sarp=1&scc=1' in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to DENY.
```

But I really need to to be able to show that authentication process in a frame. How can solve it?

Comment: OAuth isn't meant to happen in a frame, it's designed to be separate from your website and handled by the OAuth provider (in this case, Google). You can set up a redirect url for after they approve/reject the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and never will. It's a security risk and accounts.google.com and authentication is a high security area.